# Deploy react.js app /dist folder to heroku from gitlab

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, gitlab, pipeline

Im tryig to deploy my dist folder of a project from gitlab to heroku,
gitlab ci:

```
image: node:8.10.0-alpine
cache:
  key: "alpine"
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - build
  - production

build:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
  tags:
    - docker
  only:
    - master

production:
  type: deploy
  stage: production
  image: ruby:latest
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - cd dist
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=app --api-key=api-key
  only:
    - master
```

when the process runs i get: sh: 
0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory
deploy failed, build exited with code 1
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue adding --skip_cleanup to the end of dpl command.

There was a "git stash --all"happening before the deploy.

Example:

`dpl --provider=heroku --app=your-app-name --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY --skip_cleanup`

Hope it helps.